# How to do `unsubscribe` when I got error in the pipeline of rxjs?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

How to do `unsubscribe` when I got error in the pipeline?

I do subscribe to the `subjectPipe` pipeline outside `doWork` function.

Inside `doWork` function I throw an error (can be as part of my logic flow).

Everything works as expected but `subjectPipe` is log: "in subject error" and because I using `take(1)` I thought it should unsubscribe, But it does not happen because the complete function is not invoke.

How to make it `unsubscribe` when error happens?

The only thing I can think of is to create variable `error$` and use `takeUntil` and then on error function to invoke `error$`. but I don't want to do it because is extra variable and the code will be messy if I do it for every case I have.

[stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-4wdsam?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts)

```
import { Subject, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { map, switchMap, take, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

console.clear();

const doWork = () => {
  const subject = new Subject();

  const work = () => {
    throw new Error('bla');
  };

  const subjectPipe = subject.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      console.log('in subject pipeline');
    }),
    switchMap(() => work())
  );

  subjectPipe.subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('in subjectPipe next'),
    error: () => console.log('in subjectPipe error'),
    complete: () => console.log('in subjectPipe complete'),
  });

  return { subject, subjectPipe };
};

const { subject, subjectPipe } = doWork();

subjectPipe
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(() => console.log('continue the pipe...'))
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('in subject next'),
    error: () => console.log('in subject error'),
    complete: () => console.log('in subject complete'),
  });

subject.next(null);
```

Comment: You can store the `Subscription` in a variable and invoke `.unsubscribe()` on that variable in case of an error.

Comment: But for every similar use I will need extra variable to use inside the error function and outside. I want to take only one even the error happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error means completion (however, the callback associated with `complete` never gets called). So, there is no need to `unsubscribe` from the stream manually here.

In your case, if you need to call some logic in both completion and error, you can use the RxJS [finalize](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/finalize) operator, which will be called in both cases.

```js
subjectPipe
  .pipe(
    take(1),
    tap(() => console.log('continue the pipe...')),
    finalize(() =>
      console.log(
        'You can do the final stuff here, instead of `complete` callback'
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe({
    next: () => console.log('in subject next'),
    error: () => console.log('in subject error'),
    complete: () => console.log('in subject complete'),
  });
```